# setting justOne limiter for pymongo remove throws TypeError

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

On python 2.7.3, pymongo 2.7

I am trying to set the [justOne safety limiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) when removing docs from a pymongo collection.

`ufo.users` points to a valid preinitialized collection

```
>>> type(ufo.users)
<class 'pymongo.collection.Collection'>    

>>> ufo.users.remove({'emails.address': 'foo@bar.com'}, {'justOne': True})                                                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                    
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/action/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 645, in remove                                                                                   
    safe, options = self._get_write_mode(safe, **kwargs)                                                                                                                              
  File "/home/action/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 693, in _get_write_mode                                                                              
    validate_boolean('safe', safe)                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/home/action/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 75, in validate_boolean                                                                              
    raise TypeError("Wrong type for %s, value must be a boolean" % (option,))                                                                                                         
TypeError: Wrong type for safe, value must be a boolean
```

Setting the justOne value to 'True','true', 1, or '1' all provide that same error message.

Looking at my the local cache of packages, I found the function in `pymongo/common.py` that is supposed to do validation:

```
def validate_boolean(option, value):                                                                                                                                                  
    """Validates that 'value' is 'true' or 'false'.                                                                                                                                   
    """                                                                                                                                                                               
    if isinstance(value, bool):                                                                                                                                                       
        return value                                                                                                                                                                  
    elif isinstance(value, basestring):                                                                                                                                               
        if value not in ('true', 'false'):                                                                                                                                            
            raise ConfigurationError("The value of %s must be "                                                                                                                       
                                     "'true' or 'false'" % (option,))                                                                                                                 
        return value == 'true'                                                                                                                                                        
    raise TypeError("Wrong type for %s, value must be a boolean" % (option,))
```

And... I don't get it.  I tried passing 'true' and True....

Is this a bug in the package?

What do I need to do to set the justOne option correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under pymongo the argument is a little different, as in the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.remove)

```
ufo.users.remove({'emails.address': 'foo@bar.com'}, safe=True)
```

And that should do the trick

Comment: Credit left in code comments https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/meteorUFO/commit/ff39fe4d133967abe58f5ed6801dbe8dab9f3717

Comment: Seems to be depreciated now (from v3.0), as per [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.remove) link above:  `DEPRECATED - Use delete_one() or delete_many() instead`.